# How to pass an IEnumerable or queryable list of properties from Controller to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, mvvm, ienumerable, viewbag

I really hope you can help me out, as I am struggling with this issue for days now.. I am currently programming a web application that would grant users access to coupon codes for online shops.

What I use: VB.net, Entity Framework, MVC (MVVM), MS SQL Server.

This is my first post on SO and my native language is not English, nor am I a very advanced hobby programmer, pls accept my apologies just in case there already is an appropriate answer which I was not able to find due to just not knowing what exactly to search for :/

I have a few tables that are linked with many-to-many relations via a relation table: tblMerchantsInfo, tblProductsInfo,tblCouponsInfo, tblRelations

I have set up my View to expect a ViewModel that contains all the neccessary information for my View to be as useful as possible, BUT I just cannot figure out how to pass a list(?) of tbl.ProductsInfo.prodCategoryName to my view via ViewBag or ViewData.

From my ViewModel I can get a list of ALL the categories that exist in the database, however, this list contains duplicates which I would like to avoid so that I can set up an Actionlink for each distinct category.

View:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of Rabattverwaltung.CouponInfoViewModelList)" Language="VB" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
    <!--[more stuff going on here]-->
</head> 
<body>
    Filter by categories:
    <%For Each cat In Model.CouponInfoViewModel%>
        <a href="/SearchCoupons/Index/?Category=<%= cat.ProductCategory%>"> <%= cat.ProductCategory%>
        </a>
    <%Next%>
</body>
```

Would give me a list of all categories, including duplicates. That´s why I thought of passing an IEnumerable to the View using ViewBag or ViewData.

I (try to?) create it like that in my controller:

```vb
Dim CatList As New List(Of IEnumerable)
For Each DistinctCat In (From prod In database.tblProducts Select prod)
    CatList .Add(DistinctCat .prodCategory.Distinct)
Next
ViewBag.AllCategoriesList = catList
```

this results in an Error "Value cannot be null.". When I delete the "distinct" term it would create the List and pass it to my view. I was not able to figure out how to loop through that list and find only distinct items :/

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Edit: How could I get distinct categories out of my viewmodel instead of passing a list via Viewbag? Maybe this is a better way, I guess :/

Comment: If you have solved your problem,, add your own answer and accept it to close this out (and remove the edit from your question)

Comment: The initial question persists: How can I get distinct values from my (inherited) ViewModel without passing a list via ViewBag to my View.

Answer (score 0):

I JUST FOUND A SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM :'D DAYUMN, this issue was buggin me O.Ô

Just in case some future noob will have the same problem I had:

in my Controller I have this:

```
 Dim categoryList As New List(Of IEnumerable)
    For Each DistinctCategory In (From prod In database.tblProducts Select prod.prodcategor< Distinct)
        categoryList .Add(DistinctCategor)
    Next

    ViewBag.allCategoriesList = categoryList
```

While in my View I have:

```
<% For Each cat In ViewBag.allCategoriesList %>
                        <a href="/Index/?category=<%= cat%>"> <%=cat%></a>
                    <%Next%>
```

Now I can select this Link from my View to pass back the filter for category and only select the products that are in this particular category.
I just couldn't figure out how to get these unique values out of my ViewModel, thus, I would be really happy to see any suggestions not using ViewBag (Y)

*happy*